# How to fix mandrill / mailchimp transactional email issue recipient-domain-mismatch

Tags: email, transactions, mailchimp, mandrill

Mandrill is rejecting any emails sent to a domain that doesn't match my verified domain but it's not clear why this is happening.

How do I allow outgoing email to be sent to any public domain such as gmail that won't match my domain?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There is two possible cause for this issue:

**- 1. You're on a Trial plan (aka DEMO MODE)**

While in demo mode, you can only send to verified [sending domains](https://mandrillapp.com/settings/sending-domains) that you've added to the account. This restriction is lifted when blocks are purchased and the account is fully activated.

**- 2. Your DNS settings are incorrect**

```
Your mail will be rejected unless sent from a verified domain with valid DNS records.
```

**Here are two articles related to those issues:**

- https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360049504074-Mailchimp-Transactional-Email-Demo
- https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038743494-How-to-Set-up-Sending-Domains

Having the right setting for DKIM is also very important. In my case I was actually dealing with both issues.

The status of my DNS Setting when I posted this issue were:

- Verified Domain ✅
- DKIM valid ✅
- SPF valid ✅

To confirm if you have DNS issues:

1. Go to Settings > Domain >
2. click on 'Test DNS Settings'

When I did that it updated my ✅ valid DNS setting to invalid ❌. Turns out, I had entered the full « mandrill._domainkey.example.com » for the NAME of my TXT in the record, instead of «  mandrill._domainkey ». So my DKIM wasn’t  **"missing"**  BUT it was invalid; which updated the status to DKIM valid.:

That happened because when I first set my DKIM settings I forgot to recheck after 60 minutes.

```
Your DKIM record is valid, but it will take a bit for DNS providers to all see that it is. We'll recheck your record in 60 minutes.
```

**SUMMARY**

If you don't want to run into the same issue. When you first setup your account; Make sure to click 'Test DNS Settings' after 60min to confirm that your DNS settings are still « valid » and make sure that you're using a PAID subscription since in DEMO mode, you can't send email outside our verified domains.

Comment: To clarify it, I have a fully valid sending domain and I am using free plan. Can I send outside email with my full authenticated sender domain?

Comment: Mandrill is dumb now. You basically have to be on MailChimp's $17 a month plan to use it (send transactional mail)